# What is the communication protocol and port(s) used between AWS Lambda functions and the triggers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need this to restrict the ports in the security group to avoid opening all the traffic to all ports. Is it HTTPS or another protocol?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda doesn't have any open inbound ports. Lambda functions aren't continuously running, listening on ports for incoming traffic. When something invokes an AWS Lambda function it calls the AWS API, which then executes your function. If you have an AWS Lambda function configured to run in a VPC, inbound security group rules will have no affect. Assigning a security group to a Lambda function is primarily for having a security group ID you can reference in other security group rules, like when giving a Lambda function access to an RDS server.

Comment: Hello @Mark B, in my case I have the option to assign a security group to the Lambda and/or the trigger to access a Kafka server. What traffic should I open in the security group? I'm receiving an error when I have the security group assigned and it seams to be a connection issue between the trigger and the Lambda.

Comment: Are you saying it works when you allow all inbound traffic on the Lambda security group?

Comment: When I don't have a security group assigned I receive this error from the trigger:  _PROBLEM: Connection error. Please check your event source connection configuration._
And when I have a security group assigned to the lambda and the trigger (Just allowing outbound connections to the Kafka server) I get a different error from the trigger: _PROBLEM: Connection error. Your VPC must be able to connect to Lambda and STS, as well as Secrets Manager if authentication is required. You can provide access by configuring PrivateLink or a NAT Gateway._

Comment: So you haven't actually tried it with a security group assigned to Lambda, with no inbound rules?

Comment: Yes, I tried with no inbound rules, just with outbound to the Kafka server, and it doesn't work

Comment: It "doesn't work" how? What is the specific issue? If it's that 2nd issue you listed it is not related to security groups, you need to add a PrivateLink or NAT Gateway to your VPC.

Comment: There is function URL. If there is URL there is a port for URL. So you may configure port

Comment: @Green That is not correct. When this question was asked function URLs didn't exist. And the triggers being mentioned interact via the AWS API, not via a function URL. Further, function URLs only work via HTTPS on port 443. You can't change the port.